# How to replace @mention in string with a Text Componet with link - React Native

Tags: react-native

I am using React Native. What I need to do is from a text that I extract from the DB to apply a format (font color, link) to make @mentions, when searching if in the text finds 1 single match makes replacement all good, but if there are several @mentions in the text, it throws me an error.

Text example:

> hey what happened @-id:1- everything ok ?? and you @-id:2-  @-id:3- @-id:4-

//// **listusers its array, example: [idusuario: "1", usuario: "@luigbren", format: "@-id:1-".....]**

```
const PatternToComponent = (text, usuarios,) => {
    let mentionsRegex = new RegExp(/@-(id:[0-9]+)-/, 'gim');
    let matches = text.match(mentionsRegex);
    if (matches && matches.length) {
        matches = matches.map(function (match, idx) {
            let usrTofind = matches[idx]
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            const mentFormat = listusers.filter(function (item) { 
                const itemData = item.format;
                return itemData.indexOf(usrTofind) > -1;
            });
            if (mentFormat.length > 0) {
                let idusuario = mentFormat[0].idusuario
                let replc = mentFormat[0].usuario

                console.log(usrTofind) //// here find @-id:1-
                console.log(replc)   //// here is @luigbren for replace

                ////////// now here replace part of the string, @-id:1- with a <Text> component 
                ///////// with @luigbren and the link, this is repeated for every @mention found

                parts = text.split(usrTofind);
                for (var i = 1; i < parts.length; i += 2) {
                  parts[i] = <Text key={i} style={{ color: '#00F' }} onPress={() => { alert('but this is'); }}>{replc}</Text>;
                }
                return text = parts;
                /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            } else {
                return text
            }
        });
    } else {
        return text
    }
    return text
};
```

in this way the code works well for me only when in the text there is only one mention, example '*hey what happened @-id:1- everything ok ??*' , but when placing more than one mention it gives me an error, example: '*hey what happened @-id:1- everything ok ?? @-id:2- @-id:3-*' ...

Error:

> TypeError: text.split is not a function

And if instead of placing `parts = text.split(usrTofind);` I place `parts = text.toString().split(usrTofind);` it gives me this error:

> [Object Object]

### Update

I found the solution. I found another simple way to replace part of the text with the `<Text>` component, using this method:

```
funcMentToLinks = (text, idusuario) => {
const regex = /\@[id:([0-9]+]/g;
            const splitText = text.split(regex)
            if (splitText.length <= 1) {
                return text;
            }
            const matches = text.match(regex);
            return splitText.reduce(function (arr, element, index) {
                if (matches[index]) {
                    return [arr, element, <Text key={index} style={{ backgroundColor: '#ceedf1', fontWeight: 'bold', color: '#4f73c4' }} onPress={() => this.callmyopc(idusuario)}>{replc}</Text>,]
                } else {
                    return [arr, element]
                }

            }, []);
}
```

but now I have a problem, I can't find a way to call a function to navigate to another section or invoke direct the `this.props.navigation.navigate('opc')`, if i put my function .. example: `onPress={() => this.callmyopc(idusuario)}` gives me an error

Error:

> _this2.callmyopc is not a function

if i put it this way `onPress={() => {this.props.navigation.navigate('opc', { idperf: idusuario })}}` gives me an error..
Error:

> Cannot read property 'navigation' of undefined

Note: the functions this.props.navigation.navigate if they work for me in this same file, I use it in other functions, but in this function I cannot invoke it.

Comment: For your main error, I expect it means that `text` is not a string object in some cases. Can you put this code into an inline Stack Overflow JS runner, so that readers can help you debug?

Comment: Hello friend, thanks, I already found the solution, edit the publication, I never understood this part (into an inline Stack Overflow JS runne), I am a novice, now I run into another problem, and it is the most important .. I cannot apply the navigation.navigate